# If $F$ is free abelian and $G$ is abelian, with subgroups $R$ and $H$, and $F/R\cong G/H$, is there an isomorphism induced in this way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $F$ be a free abelian group, $R$ a subgroup of $F, G$ an abelian group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$ and $F/R$ is isomorphic to $G/H$. Does there exist a homomorphism $h:F \rightarrow G$ such that

i) $h(R) \subset H$

ii) $h^*: F/R \rightarrow G/H$ defined by $h^*(r+R)=h(r)+H$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: You have a homomorphism $F \to G/H$ with kernel $R$, which lifts to a homomorphism $F \to G$ because $F$ is free (if you use the right definition of free abelian group then that follows straight from the definition), and that gives you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Actually this holds in every algebraic category $\mathcal{C}$: If $F,G \in \mathcal{C}$, $R$ is a congruence relation on $F$ and $H$ is a congruence on $G$, and $F$ is free, then every homomorphism $F/R \to G/H$ is induced by a homomorphism $F \to G$ mapping $R$ to $H$. The reason is simply that free objects are [projective](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/projective+object) with respect to surjective homomorphisms (not arbitrary epimorphisms, but we don't need this). In elementary terms, choose a basis of $F$, and for every basis element lift its image in $G/H$ to some element of $G$. This extends to a homomorphism $F \to G$.

Comment: In what generality is it true that epimorphisms are surjections of underlying sets? For groups this is a non-trivial result and for rings this is false. Unless I'm mistaken you need this for the implication "free $\implies$ projective" or you need to restrict the epimorphisms under consideration (regular epimorphisms would be fine here).

Comment: Oh, sure. I've added this.

Comment: We can extend a homomorphism $h:F \rightarrow G$ from $F/R \cong G/H$. I don't know how to prove  $h^*:  F/R \rightarrow G/H$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: $h^*$ is *equal* to the given isomorphism.